# Laravel new command warning

Tags: laravel

I am getting the following warning while running laravel new command.

> PHP Warning:  ZipArchive::extractTo(): File exists in /home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/laravel/installer/src/NewCommand.php on line 99

This is followed by a big php trace.

How can I remove this and what does this mean?

Comment: What exact 'new command' you are running?

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek, probably `laravel new` from the Laravel Installer.

Comment: Yes. Its 'laravel new'.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're doing `laravel new blog` in a folder that already has a blog folder within it.

Either delete that folder or do `laravel new blog1`.